# Creating normal distribution graph with multiple lines using JFreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to create a normal distribution graph, with more than one line on it.

Exactly like this one:

[image]

I searched the internet but only found some guide to common lines graph, not normal distribution graph.

I can't figure out how to do this, please help

Below is part of my code

```
public ChartPanel getPanelNormalWeightAndSpecies() {
    double mean = getMean();
    double std = getStd(mean);

    Function2D normal = new NormalDistributionFunction2D(mean, std);
    Function2D normal2 = new NormalDistributionFunction2D(0.0, 1.0);

    XYDataset dataset = DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D(normal, 50, 150, 100, "Normal");
    XYDataset dataset2 = DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D(normal2, 50, 150, 100, "Normal2");
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            "Test",
            "X", 
            "Y", 
            dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            true,
            true,
            false
            );
    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    XYItemRenderer xyitem = plot.getRenderer();

    plot.setDataset(1, dataset2);
    plot.setRenderer(1, xyitem);

    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    return chartPanel;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is on track, there is an example of how to do exactly what you want in the JFreeChart Samples and you can get the source code by buying the [developer guide](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html)

Comment: I solved it by your help. I'm not going to buy it because I just don't code Java as work. Anyway, thanks!